# show if you don't have Internet connection with dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog

When opening the application and the device is not connected on the internet, `Dialog` pops-up and if positive button clicks, app closes.

It's simple but I can't seem to find any.

My MainActivity: (actually has another name HomeAcitivty)

```
package tk.protvapp.protv;




import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void onClickToScreenfox(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, FoxActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClickToScreendch(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DisneychannelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClickToScreendxd(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DisneyxdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClickToScreendlk(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LinksActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: plz select an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This is the class i made to check internet connection.

```
public class ConnectionChecker {
private Context context;

public ConnectionChecker(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}
public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){

    ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(conn!=null)
    {
        NetworkInfo[] info = conn.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;

}
}
```

Then on your mainActivity check connection then create a dialog if not connected.

```
if(!new ConnectionChecker(this).isConnectedToInternet()){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("No internet connection");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish;
                }
            });
            builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit/add this to your HomeActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) {
        terminatingAlertMessage("No Internet. :(");
    }

}

private void terminatingAlertMessage(String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         //Connection Check

            public boolean checkConnection() {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (null == activeNetwork)
                    return false;
                return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

        private void ExitAlertMessage(String message) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }

    //////use
     if (checkConnection()) {
/// do what  you want
                                    } else {
                                        ExitAlertMessage("Please Check Internet Connection.");
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in your HomeActivity onCreate

```
              //if no internet
               alertForExit();

            private void alertForExit(){  

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Poor internet connection!Please try after sometime").setCancelable(
                false).setPositiveButton("Quit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(startMain);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

}